# Making an HTTPS request more readable

Tags: ruby, error-handling, https, openssl

I think the snippet is too nested having too many blocks. It needs to be refactored to make the logic more readable.

- The try exception is the first level block
- `Timeout::timeout` is the next level block
- Some loop-like blocks inside it

How can I make it more readable?

```
  def https_request(server_url, header, content)
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(@@TIMEOUT_PERIOD) do
        hack_ssl_options
        uri = URI.parse(server_url)
        https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
        https.use_ssl = true
        options_mask = OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2 + OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3 + OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMPRESSION
        https.ssl_options = options_mask
        https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
        req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = header)
        req.body = content
        headers = req.each_header.inject({}) { |h,(key, value)| h[key] = value ; h }
        resp = https.request(req)
        response_headers = resp.each_header.inject({}) { |h,(key, value)| h[key] = value ; h }
        return { code: resp.code,
                 header: response_headers,
                 body: resp.body }
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      return { code: @@timeout_error_code,
               header: nil,
               body: @@timeout_error_msg }
    rescue Exception => e
      return { code: @@unknown_error_code,
               header: nil,
               body: @@unknown_error_msg }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to answer your questions first:

- you don't need begin/end if it covers whole method, you can rescue directly from method,
- Net::HTTP already handles timeout, no need to build custom wrapper around it,

now there are few other things that should be addressed:

- inline things when possible
- don't use `@@` ever, use constants if you need to
- don't rescue from `Exception`, rescue from `StandardError` instead (or nothing as ruby defaults to StandardError anyways)
- try to be consistent with returned result, i.e. `header` should always return hash, never nil. Otherwise you will need to add conditions in places where you handle code
- `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` this is bad, you want to verify certificate.
- do not use Net::HTTP, there are much more rubout gems available, i.e. Typhoeus

Finally it could be rewritten to something like this:

```
def https_request(server_url, header, content)
  hack_ssl_options
  uri = URI.parse(server_url)

  connection = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  connection.use_ssl = true
  connection.ssl_options = OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2 + OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3 + OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_COMPRESSION
  connection.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  connection.read_timeout = TIMEOUT_PERIOD

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = header)
  request.body = content

  response = connection.request(req)

  { code: response.code, header: response.to_hash, body: response.body }
rescue Net::ReadTimeout => e  
  { code: CODE_TIMEOUT, header: {}, body: e.message }
rescue => e
  { code: CODE_UNKNOWN, header: {}, body: e.message }
end
```

This code works slightly different from your original version, you may need to adjust it.